# Groupby sequence of values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 90, 100, 200, 11], 
        'b': ['x', 'y', 'h', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x', 'a', 'z']
    }
)
```

And this is the way that I want to group it:

```
0    1  x
1   10  y
2   20  h
3   30  z

4   40  x
5   90  z

6  100  x
7  200  a
8   11  z
```

I want to start grouping when there is x in column `b` and end the group when there is z in `b`. Obviously I want to include everything that comes in between x and z like the first group for example.

I tried the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104011/groupby-streak-of-numbers-in-one-column-of-pandas-dataframe) but still couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the grouper made by @[*mozway*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76335373/16120011) answer :

```
# map True/False to x/z
m1 = df["b"].map({"x": True, "z": False})
m2 = m1.ffill().fillna(False)
# only keep last x's
m3 = m1.shift(-1).ne(True)
m4 = m2&m3
​
grp = (m1&m3).cumsum().where(m4|m4.shift(), 0)
#[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
​
dfs = {f"group_{n}": g for n,g in df.groupby(grp)}
```

​
Ouptut :

```
print(dfs)

{'group_1':  a  b
 0   1  x
 1  10  y
 2  20  h
 3  30  z,
 'group_2':  a  b
 4  40  x
 5  90  z,
 'group_3':  a  b
 6  100  x
 7  200  a
 8   11  z}
```

Comment: Nice approach :p

Comment: haha, there's nothing more original ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 90, 100, 200, 11], 
        'b': ['x', 'y', 'h', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x', 'a', 'z']
    }
)

# Create a new column called `group`
df['group'] = df['b'].str.extract(r'(x(.*)z)').fillna('').str.strip()

# Group the DataFrame by the `group` column
df = df.groupby('group').agg({'a': 'first', 'b': 'last'})

print(df)

# Output:
#   group  a  b
# 0     x  1  x
# 1     y 10  y
# 2     h  20  h
# 3     z  30  z
# 4     x  40  x
# 5     z  90  z
# 6     x 100  x
# 7     a 200  a
# 8     z  11  z
```